# html5 showNotification

Tags: html, html5-notifications

I have created a desktop notification with `window.webkitNotifications.createNotification()`.
I've seen that gmail use an onclick event on the notification for the redirection, how is it made?

Answer (score 4):

i have found the solution:

```
var notification = window.webkitNotifications.createNotification(url,title,teaser); 
notification.onclick = function(x) { window.focus(); this.cancel(); $(location).attr('href',path);};
notification.show();
```